# Getting one div to span vertically alongside two divs?

Tags: html, css-float

So, I have been working on a small showcase or portfolio type site for a friend of mine, and I have hit a brick wall. I apologize for not having copies of all my efforts saved as when I am trying to fix something I tend to just keep making changes and overwriting. Anyway, if you direct your attention to http://www.djcpro.net/GSFlook/projects.html you can see what I am about to try to explain. I am familiar with clearing divs after a float to get divs to display next to one another, but what I am having trouble conquering is getting the right div to display alongside **both** of the divs on the left, so that the two on the left are not affected by the one on the right. No matter how I move the code around, or what methods I try I can only seem to get the iframe to display next to either the top left div or the bottom left div, but not span vertically alongside both of the left divs. I was hoping someone here would perhaps see what I am missing. If not, I shall revert to tables since they do what I want. Thanks ahead of time for any input.

Comment: You should put into Services Offered and Quick Info into a container div called side panel and another main div into which Our Company will go.

Comment: do you want something that looks like this: |_|_|_| or two divs stacked on top of each other and then one running the length of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes to your styles:

```
#content{
    width:990px;
}

#company_info{
    margin-left:0px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:90px;
}

#quick_head_p{
    /*Dont need clear */
    width:207px;
    float:left;
}
```

When I apply those changes, it works just fine.

Comment: I knew it was something simple I wasn't seeing. I was focusing too hard on the div on the right and not enough on the one that was being pushed down. Thank you so much!